# Musician Jumble

Tags: music, anagram

I have a lot of free time, so I asked my friend for music suggestions.

My friend, knowing that I am bored with time on my hands agreed, but gave me the suggestions in the form of a puzzle.

On a sheet of paper, they wrote down twelve words:

```
BLAND
BOY
CHAPTER
CLIP
EARTH
ELEMENTS
IONIC
MESS
PICKET
POEMS
RAIN
SNIP
```

They also gave me some instructions:

> Assemble the words in six pairs which form anagrams of music artists. From the artists which contain the letter P next to a vowel, take the first letters of their second words. From the remaining artists, take their last letters.

"There," my friend proclaimed, "seven suggestions spanning several genres and media – if you're up to the challenge. Oh, and some final things since I'm feeling nice: the artists all have one major thing in common, at least one of the pairs is made of adjacent words in the list, and exactly one of the pairs does not contain the letter N."

**The question(s):**

> **Who are the artists my friend is suggesting, and what do they have in common?**

Comment: I appreciate the thought that went into the construction of this puzzle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The artists, discovered in the wiki are

> Semisonic, The Replacements, Bob Dylan, Atmosphere, Lipps Inc, Nick Pitera, and Prince

Final Answer - What do they have in common -

> All Musicians from Minnesota

Answer (score 6):

NOTE: Will (op) wanted to accept an answer, so he edited this into my answer for the theme.  Post any you solved in your own answer to get upvotes.

Working Anagram List - WIKI edit as you solve them.

1

> Ionic Mess - Semisonic (Closing Time was their hit)

2

> Chapter Elements - The Replacements

3

> Bland Boy - Bob Dylan

4

> Earth Poems - Atmosphere

5

> Snip Clip - Lipps Inc

6

> Picket Rain - Nick Pitera NOTE: No idea who this is got it by viewing wiki page of "Musicians from XXXXXXXXX"

Word List

> <s>BLAND</s>
>  <s>BOY</s>
>  <s>CHAPTER</s>
>  <s>CLIP</s>
>  <s>EARTH</s>
>  <s>ELEMENTS</s>
>  <s>IONIC</s>
>  <s>MESS</s>
>  <s>PICKET</s>
>  <s>POEMS</s>
>  <s>RAIN</s>
>  <s>SNIP</s>

So this leave us with

> Semisoni**C**
>  The **R**eplacements
>  Bob Dyla**N**
>  Atmospher**E**
>  Lipps **I**nc
>  Nick **P**itera
>  C R N E I P = **PRINCE**

Comment: Nicely done. I obviously misread the intent of "letterS"